# Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler NOT FOUND - I want to import this namespace in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winapi, namespaces, scheduled-tasks

I've been looking at sample code for interfacing with the Windows Task Scheduler, and most of them import the namespace:

```
Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler
```

When I go to import it, it's not there within `Win32`.

Does anyone know why I can't import it? I'm assuming that something isn't registered correctly on my machine, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Just for the record, I can start the Scheduled Task component under Accessories. I'm using VS 2008 (VB.Net) with Windows XP Professional.

Comment: NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your project, you need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll`  that was part of the [codeplex download](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/).

[The usual place is to create a folder as part of your source tree for external Libs and reference from there.]

**Update**: Current practice would be to use NuGet to manage a dependency: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/